# Laravel Bulk validation

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to apply one validation to array of objects in laravel ?
i need to validate list of users email address for example.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'users[].email' => 'email|unique:users'
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change `[]` in to `*`

This is how store action in user controller will look

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'users.*.email' => 'email|unique:users'
    ]);

}
```

Please refer the docs -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays

Answer (score 3):

Yess you can validate arrays like

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'users.*.email' => 'email|unique:users'

    ]);
```

For more information have a look in the docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays